# how can we give react native usetheme typescript?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo-router

I have a themeprovider in react native , expo-router. I have various colors according to dark and light mode and I write typescript.

When I access it with the useTheme() function on other pages, typescript only shows its specified types. How can I give my own types?

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";

const ThemeWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const scheme = useColorScheme();

  const ThemeColors = {
    light: {
      colors: {
        background: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        transparentBackground: "rgba(255, 255, 255,0.7)",
        lightBackground: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        primary: "#4E4FEB",
        primary2: "#068FFF",
        border: "#B8B8B9",
        shadow: "black",
        text: "#131313",

        card: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        notification: "rgb(255, 59, 48)",
      },
      padding: {
        default: 30,
      },
      dark: false,
    },
    dark: {
      colors: {
        background: "black",
        transparentBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7)",
        lightBackground: "#191919",
        primary: "#4E4FEB",
        primary2: "#068FFF",
        border: "#B6B6B6",
        shadow: "#2C3333",
        text: "rgb(229, 229, 231)",

        card: "rgb(18, 18, 18)",
        notification: "rgb(255, 69, 58)",
      },
      padding: { default: 30 },
      dark: true,
    },
  };

  return <ThemeProvider value={ThemeColors[scheme]}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
};

export default ThemeWrapper;
```